# UIActivityViewController exclude all UIActivityCategoryAction

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have instantiated a [`UIActivityViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011976-CH1-SW7). Conveniently, I can exclude individual [activity types](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivity_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Built_in_Activity_Types) using the property `excludedActivityTypes`.

I now want to exclude the [activity category](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivity_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIActivityCategory) `UIActivityCategoryAction`. How can I exclude an activity category, as opposed to an individual activity type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per current documentation, you can't but you could build an array holding all the individual types of an `UIActivityCategory` and pass it to the `excludedActivityTypes` property.

If you fear that over time Apple could add new activity types and your `UIActivityViewController` will show the new types, fear not because it will not happen unless you update the app using the new SDK. So you're safe in this regard.

Comment: Thanks for the further details! My greatest fear is regarding the non-built-in activity types. It's possible the user has an app (not in the default list) which in the category `UIActivityCategoryAction`.

Comment: @Randomblue I think you are confusing `Extensions` with `UIActivities`. You can use the custom UIActivities you'll build at your own discretion, when you want, how you want like the built-in ones. If I misunderstood your comment, please rephrase.

Comment: The problem is that as of iOS 8 third party apps can install their own activity handlers. So how could I exclude all third party apps from the UIActivityViewController?